# using Enum in traits in scala

Tags: scala, enums

i have a trait named UserT and a class DirectUserT extending the trait 
i want to add enum in the trait so that child classes can use it 
i have made a scala Object UserStatus which extends Enumeration
now i want to have this enum in my trait so that child classes can use it but i dont know how should i do is ?

my enum object

```
package testlogic

    object UserStatus extends Enumeration{

        type  UserStatus = Value
        val ACTIVE , INACTIVE , BLOCKED , DELETED = Value

    }
```

here is my code for UserT

```
package testlogic
 import testlogic.UserStatus._
trait UserT {

  var name : String = ""
  def setName( aName: String)= {
    name = aName
  }
  def getName : String = {
    name
  }

}
```

DirectUserT.scala

```
package testlogic


    class DirectuserT extends  UserT {

     var currentStatus =BLOCKED
     //println(currentStatus)

    }
```

eclipse shows error on BLOCKED

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add

```
import testlogic.UserStatus._
```

to you class DirectUserT.scala

Or add it within your trait:

```
trait UserT {
  import testlogic.UserStatus._
}
```

Comment: please tell me is it the right approach?
i mean in this case it is not inheriting enum from the trait it is just directly importing enum and using it ?

Comment: you are using the values defined 'inside' the enum. hence we should do that. or directly UserStatus.BLOCKED